# Is there an efficient way to group a datatable by unique rows and columns at the same time in R?

Tags: r, datatable

I have a datatable like this:

[Overview of data:][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WabXJ.png

[where I want the end result to become:][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSEan.png

So far, this code produces the correct values for each variable, however, it is not nicely stacked in a 4x4 table:

```
data <- data_raw %>%
  mutate(Område = as.factor(data_raw$Område),
         yield = as.numeric(`Yield (%)`),
         yield_range =as.factor(case_when(yield <= 4.25 ~"3.00 - 4.25",
                                yield <= 5.50 ~"4.30 - 5.50",
                                yield <= 6.75 ~"5.55 - 6.75",
                                yield <= 8.00 ~"5.60 - 8,00"
                                )))

data_group <- data %>%                                 
  group_by(data_group$Område, data_group$yield_range) %>%
  summarize(no = n())
```

[Produces this result:][3]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cfNX.png

Is there a easy way to rearrange this last table to resemble the result I want in [2] ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column with the category as ranges.

```
data_raw <- within(data_raw, {   
  Yield.cat <- NA 
  Yield.cat[`Yield (%)` <= 4.25] <- "3.00-4.25"
  Yield.cat[`Yield (%)` > 4.25 & `Yield (%)` <= 5.50] <- "4.25-5.50"
  Yield.cat[`Yield (%)` > 5.50 & `Yield (%)` <= 6.75] <- "5.50-6.75"
  Yield.cat[`Yield (%)` > 6.75] <- "6.75-8.00"
})
```

and convert into a frequency table

```
out <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(data_raw$Yield.cat, data_raw$Område))
```

However, with your above try you can just create a frequency table

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data_raw %>%
  mutate(Område = as.factor(data_raw$Område),
         yield = as.numeric(`Yield (%)`),
         yield_range =as.factor(case_when(yield <= 4.25 ~"3.00 - 4.25",
                                          yield <= 5.50 ~"4.30 - 5.50",
                                          yield <= 6.75 ~"5.55 - 6.75",
                                          yield <= 8.00 ~"5.60 - 8,00"
         )))

out <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(data$yield_range, data$Område))
```